# How to perform segue after 5 files download request completed in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, segue, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to perform segue after downloading.
I tried BlockOperation firstly, but I failed.

Below is my code.

```
    let operationQ = OperationQueue()

    let taskArray: [BlockOperation]

    for index in 0..<songsList.count {

        let eachSong = songsList[index]

        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/"
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsURL.appending("song\(index).m4a"))
            print("song\(index).m4a is downloading")

            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        taskArray.append(BlockOperation(block: let task = {
            Alamofire.download(eachSong, to: destination).response { _ in

                //                    print(response.response)
            }

            }))

taskArray[4].completionBlock = { performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextVC", sender: self) }
```

I want to set a array of [BlockOperation] firstly.

Then, trying to append Alamofire.download in this array, but failed.

I am not sure which part got wrong, maybe each block need a different name?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks do not always terminate in the same order that you pushed them into the queue.

You also must use UI operations on the main thread!

See this post [How is it possible to perform multiple Alamofire requests that are finished one after another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919852/how-is-it-possible-to-perform-multiple-alamofire-requests-that-are-finished-one)

You can also read [this blog post](http://www.thomashanning.com/a-simple-nsblockoperation-example/) for an example of using `BlockOperation`